# How to create array from a function?

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, octave

gdp_p_h and p are vectors. But for some reason this doesn't want to work.
I keep getting an error saying: "A(I) = X: X must have the same size as I"

```
for entry = gdp_p_h
      function_array(end + 1) = polyval(p,entry)
end;
```

Comment: what about `function_array(end+1,:)` ?

Comment: Do not forget to accept the answer then, so it is useful for future "lost programmers"! :)

Answer (score 2):

When using `polyval`, if entry is an array it will return something the same size.

In your case you are using the loop pretty badly, so entry will be a whole array and `function_array(end+1)` is only a single number, so it can not store an array.

2 options:

If you want to keep the loop (if you have more things inside), write it properly!

I am guessing that you want:

```
for ii=1:length(gdp_p_h)
     entry=gdp_p_h(ii);
     function_array(end + 1) = polyval(p,entry);
end
```

Else,  if that's the only thing you are doing inside the loop, you just dont need it.

```
function_array=polyval(p,gdp_p_h);
```

will do the job.

---

Learn how to write `for` loops here: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/for.html